# Converting a dataframe into JSON (in pyspark) and then selecting desired fields

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark. I have a dataframe that contains the results of some analysis. I converted that dataframe into JSON so I could display it in a Flask App:

```
results = result.toJSON().collect()
```

An example entry in my json file is below. I then tried to run a for loop in order to get specific results:

```
{"userId":"1","systemId":"30","title":"interest"}

for i in results:
    print i["userId"]
```

This doesn't work at all and I get errors such as: Python (json) : TypeError: expected string or buffer

I used `json.dumps` and `json.loads` and still nothing - I keep on getting errors such as string indices must be integers, as well as the above error.

I then tried this:

```
  print i[0]
```

This gave me the first character in the json "{" instead of the first line. I don't really know what to do, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

If the result of `result.toJSON().collect()` is a JSON encoded string, then you would use `json.loads()` to convert it to a `dict`. The issue you're running into is that when you iterate a `dict` with a `for` loop, you're given the keys of the `dict`. In your `for` loop, you're treating the key as if it's a `dict`, when in fact it is just a `string`. Try this:

```
# toJSON() turns each row of the DataFrame into a JSON string
# calling first() on the result will fetch the first row.
results = json.loads(result.toJSON().first())

for key in results:
    print results[key]

# To decode the entire DataFrame iterate over the result
# of toJSON()

def print_rows(row):
    data = json.loads(row)
    for key in data:
        print "{key}:{value}".format(key=key, value=data[key])


results = result.toJSON()
results.foreach(print_rows)
```

**EDIT:** The issue is that [`collect`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.collect) returns a `list`, not a `dict`. I've updated the code. Always read the docs.

> collect() Return a list that contains all of the elements in this RDD.
>
> Note This method should only be used if the resulting array is
> expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver’s
> memory.

**EDIT2:** I can't emphasize enough, always <s>[read the docs.](http://takwatanabe.me/pyspark/generated/generated/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toJSON.html)</s>

**EDIT3:** Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492402/using-foreachrdd-and-foreach-to-iterate-over-an-rdd-in-pyspark).

Comment: Hi @Allie, I get this error: TypeError: expected string or buffer when I run that - is there any reason why?

Comment: Most likely it's because `collect` returns a `dict` and not a JSON encoded string. Try removing `json.loads`

Comment: Still not working, I'm now getting a str indices error?

Comment: Hi Allie, I'm getting: 

`obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()`

TypeError: expected string or buffer now

Comment: Did a bit more research on `toJSON` and updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Allie, sorry to come back again! Still not working - I'm now getting this: TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable?

Comment: `RDD`s have a `forEach` function to iterate.

Comment: do  you receive  "TypeError: expected string or buffer " probably only when you use foreachPartition instead foreach

Comment: The types returned aren't the same
>>> df.toJSON().foreach(x)
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'unicode'>
>>> df.toJSON().foreachPartition(x)
<type 'generator'>
<type 'generator'>
<type 'generator'>
<type 'generator'>

Comment: The second link appears to be an attack site asking the user to install a Chrome plugin.

Answer (score 16):

```
import json
>>> df = sqlContext.read.table("n1")
>>> df.show()
+-----+-------+----+---------------+-------+----+
|   c1|     c2|  c3|             c4|     c5|  c6|
+-----+-------+----+---------------+-------+----+
|00001|Content|   1|Content-article|       |2018|
|00002|Content|null|Content-article|Content|2015|
+-----+-------+----+---------------+-------+----+

>>> results = df.toJSON().map(lambda j: json.loads(j)).collect()
>>> for i in results: print i["c1"], i["c6"]
... 
00001 2018
00002 2015
```

Comment: This was so helpful. Thanks for a simple solution that is easy to follow.

Answer (score 14):

Here is what worked for me:

```
df_json = df.toJSON()

for row in df_json.collect():
    #json string
    print(row) 

    #json object
    line = json.loads(row) 
    print(line[some_key])
```

Keep in mind that using .collect() is not advisable, since it collects the distributed data frames, and defeats the purpose of using data frames.

Comment: Then what to use instead of collect() for this purpose? What is the more efficient way? @Zeitgeist

Comment: @Johnas There may not be a good efficient way to do the same exact thing with DataFrames (I am not up to date on this). I was just warning that .collect() is inefficient. It may be ok for smaller DFs. Another way may be not using DataFrames altogether, since using .collect() reduces the benefits that DFs provide. It all depends on the use case.

Answer (score 6):

To get an array of python dicts:

```
results = df.toJSON().map(json.loads).collect()
```

To get an array of JSON strings:

```
results = df.toJSON().collect()
```

To get a JSON string (i.e. a JSON string of an array):

```
results = df.toPandas().to_json(orient='records')
```

and using that to get an array of Python dicts:

```
results = json.loads(df.toPandas().to_json(orient='records'))
```